# I cannot access protectedSessionStore from other pages except current page in blazor

Tags: c#, .net, session, blazor, blazor-server-side

If I do not leave the page where I am logged in, I hand session in any case. However Although I open a new page in the same browser, I can not access it. why does this happen, any idea?

key code snippets:

Startup.cs > ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddRazorPages();
services.AddServerSideBlazor();

services.AddAuthorization();
services.AddAuthentication();

services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, UserService>();

services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddHttpClient();
```

UserService:

```
  public async Task<UserDto> GetUserSession()
        {
            var localUserJson = await protectedSessionStore.GetAsync<string>(USER_SESSION_OBJECT_KEY);
        }
```

login.razor:

```
    protected override async void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            if (await ServiceProvider.Get<UserService>().GetUserSession() != null)
            {
                NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Dashboard");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Although I open a new page in the same browser, I can not access it.

That is the expected behaviour.

Per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly#browser-storage-wasm):

> - sessionStorage is scoped to the browser tab. If the user reloads the tab, the state persists. If the user closes the tab or the browser, the state is lost. If the user opens multiple browser tabs, each tab has its own independent version of the data.

It sounds like you want LocalStorage instead:

> - localStorage is scoped to the browser's window. If the user reloads the page or closes and re-opens the browser, the state persists. If the user opens multiple browser tabs, the state is shared across the tabs. Data persists in localStorage until explicitly cleared.

Comment: first many thanks for your precious knowledge, as much as I remember, in .net, we can reach, am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you were already usiing a package for SessionStorage, they usually include a LocalStorage wrapper as well.